# How to make background SVG stretch 100% with cross browser support?

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

Check out this pen in Chrome and then Firefox:
http://codepen.io/richbrat/pen/fLdFw

In Chrome the SVG is scaling appropriately but not in Firefox. Why is that, has it got something to do with preserveAspectRatio in SVG?

The SVG is here:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/156826/bg.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out CSS

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Take a look at Browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: it can be done this way too : `background: #e8f5fa url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/156826/bg.svg') no-repeat  / 100% 100%;` (shorthand)

Comment: Thanks! Marking this as the solution although I will use GCyrillus CSS-solution, that was the thing I first tried and wanted to do. Had been trying various solutions with SVG and background-size back and forth for a while so I forgot to try it again once I got the SVG working in Chrome. :)

Answer (score 2):

For this effect that you look for, a linear background could be used as well :

[`background: #e8f5fa linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 51%, #DAEAF3 50%) ;`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uEcmB)

For the background-size, it can be written this way too:
[`background: #e8f5fa url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/156826/bg.svg') no-repeat 0 0  / 100% 100%;`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fJjml)